# How do you set an active Marker with Google Maps on Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I have a GoogleMap in my Flutter app.
When the page loads it calls on API and gets a list of geolocations which I use to create a list of markers.

My GoogleMap uses this list of markers and they display nicely, however, I would like one of them to be active.  I can't see anything in the API documentation that says this is possible.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by active marker ?

Comment: when you click on a market it shows info, and it becomes an active marker.  I cant find a way to achieve that with code only

Answer (score 3):

Use GoogleMapController to set the marker active, allMarkers here is a list of markers which might be coming from the database and the first one (index 0) will be active after execution of:

```
_googleMapController.showMarkerInfoWindow(allMarkers[0].markerId);
```

[Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/showMarkerInfoWindow.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement custom active state through `onTap` event handler.
In stateful widget create state to track selected marker and rebuild all markers comparing their IDs to the highlighted one:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GoogleMapsLabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<GoogleMapsLabPage> createState() => GoogleMapsLabPageState();
}

class GoogleMapsLabPageState extends State<GoogleMapsLabPage> {
  final preset = [
    {"id": "mountain-view", "lat": 37.421512, "lng": -122.084101},
    {"id": "san-bruno", "lat": 37.62816, "lng": -122.426491},
    {"id": "san-francisco", "lat": 37.789972, "lng": -122.390013},
    {"id": "sunnyvale", "lat": 37.403694, "lng": -122.031583}
  ];

  String _selectedOffice = '';

  List<Marker> _buildMarkers() {
    return preset.map((office) {
      return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(office['id']),
          position: LatLng(office['lat'], office['lng']),
          icon: office['id'] == _selectedOffice
              ? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue)
              : BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          consumeTapEvents: true,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _selectedOffice = office['id'];
            });
          });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.7, -122.2), zoom: 9.0),
        markers: _buildMarkers().toSet(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

By setting `consumeTapEvents` parameter to `true` we can disable default tap handling by centering the map on the marker and displaying its info window.

Answer (score 2):

There are ongoing issues in flutter related to the same thing [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29899) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33481).

Currently, It is not possible to do this via official maps SDK.

However, thanks to the community there is another forked project which has an implementation which can help you achieve this. Checkout [this](http://%20https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33481#issuecomment-536334663).

Answer (score 0):

```
   mapController.addMarker(
  MarkerOptions(
    position: LatLng(your values here),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It's best to explain what your code snippet is doing, and why this is meant to be the answer to OP's question.